# How to use an INSERT statement that have multiple SELECT sub queries each of which have their own WHERE clause criteria

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am working on creating an access based tool on my client's Virtual Machine. The access version I use basically does not support Pivot tables and it is essential I could use one - I could create one using VBA but  that seems to be quite a messy option when a query may be all I need. I have a table that has the production done by the team including their compliance status. For example

```
ID  NAME    CASE ID LEVEL   STATUS
123 John    ABC123  L1  Compliant
456 Mathew  DEF123  L2  Compliant
789 Mark    CNX93   L2  Compliant
100 Luke    SDK019  L1  Non-Compliant
```

The result I would require in another table should look like this: Name of the analyst in rows, count of the 2 different statuses in 2 columns for each analyst and the sum total of each row. A Pivoted table basically.

I've attempted some basic insert queries but none of them return how I need it to be. I do not want to use UPDATE or multiple queries - Just one query that will do the job.

I do not have any code other than some basic INSERT queries which I used for trial and error. I might not be clear but I'll be glad to clarify your questions. Much appreciated.

Comment: Edit question to show desired output as a table. What you describe sounds like a CROSSTAB query but not quite sure what you mean by 'sum total of each row'.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Forgive me, I'm unable to format for some reason. For example and basically for Level 1 Case IDs, we would have something like this,

Analyst Compliant Non-Compliant Total
John     1  1
Luke      1 1
Mark     1  1
Mathew   1  1
Total 3 1 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
select name,
       sum(iif(status = "Compliant", 1, 0)) as num_compliant,
       sum(iif(status = "Non-Compliant", 1, 0)) as num_noncompliant,
       count(*) as total
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! This works exactly how I need it. I now have the data I need along with column totals as the last row using the Totals button. However, how do I get Totals as a column (sum total of each row)?

Comment: I got this sorted @Gordon Linoff. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  left join with subquery for Compliant and Non-Compliant and group  by

```
  select t.id, t.name, count(c.id) NUM_COMPLIANT, count(n.id) NUM_NOT_COMPLIANT
  from  my_table t 
  left ( 
    select id, name, case_id, level, status 
    from my_table 
    where status  = 'Compliant' 
  ) c  on c.id = t.id 
  left ( 
    select id, name, case_id, level, status 
    from my_table 
    where status  = 'Non-Compliant' 
  ) n  on n.id = t.id 
  group by  t.id, t.name
```

Comment: Thanks @ScaisEdge: Let me try this and get back to you